# RGraph with missing data points

Tags: javascript, rgraph

I want to plot an area fill line chart with multiple series, using javascript & RGraph, for a period between two dates, but I do not have data points for every date; how do I do this with RGraph?

I cannot miss out dates in the data I pass to RGraph because although some of the series do not have that data, it might be that other series do (e.g. ABC has data for January and March, and XYZ has data for January and April).

I must have all dates for the year, which is represented with a horizontal axis showing just the month/period labels.

I have boiled this down to a simplified example below, and with a jsFiddle example on https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/25m1sc7d/1/

Both the code below and the JSFiddle show two charts controlled by the drawAll() function, which has a variable x in it. I want the second chart (cvs2) which uses x=null to *not include plotting that null* but simply draw the red line/area between 100 and 200, resulting a similar chart to the first one (cvs1).

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<script src='https://www.rgraph.net/libraries/RGraph.common.core.js'></script>
<script src='https://www.rgraph.net/libraries/RGraph.common.dynamic.js'></script>
<script src='https://www.rgraph.net/libraries/RGraph.common.effects.js'></script>
<script src='https://www.rgraph.net/libraries/RGraph.common.key.js'></script>
<script src='https://www.rgraph.net/libraries/RGraph.common.tooltips.js'></script>
<script src='https://www.rgraph.net/libraries/RGraph.drawing.rect.js'></script>
<script src='https://www.rgraph.net/libraries/RGraph.line.js'></script>
<script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'>
</script>

</head>
<body>

<canvas id='cvs1' width='900' height='300' style='border:solid 1pt red'>
    [No canvas support]
</canvas>
<hr>
<canvas id='cvs2' width='900' height='300' style='border:solid 1pt blue'>
    [No canvas support]
</canvas>


<script type='text/Javascript'>

    drawAll();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        drawAll();
    });



    function drawAll() {
        var x=150;
        var data = [[0, 50, 100, x, 200],[10,20,30,40,50]];
        drawChart('cvs1', data);

        x=null;
        var data = [[0, 50, 100, x, 200],[10,20,30,40,50]];
        drawChart('cvs2', data);
    }



    function drawChart(canvasId, data) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
        RGraph.Reset(canvas);

        canvas.width  = $(window).width() * 0.9;
        var text_size = Math.min(10, ($(window).width() / 1000) * 20 );
        var linewidth = $(window).width() > 500 ? 2 : 1;
            linewidth = $(window).width() > 750 ? 3 : linewidth;

        var line = new RGraph.Line(canvasId, data);
        line.set('chart.text.size', text_size);
        line.Set('chart.background.barcolor1', 'rgba(255,255,255,1)');
        line.Set('chart.background.barcolor2', 'rgba(255,255,255,1)');
        line.Set('chart.background.grid.color', 'rgba(238,238,238,1)');
        line.Set('chart.colors', [ 'red',  'green',  'blue']);
        line.Set('chart.linewidth', 1);
        line.Set('chart.hmargin', 15);
        line.Set('chart.labels', ['Q1\n2017','Q2','Q3','Q4','Q1\n2018']);
        line.Set('chart.gutter.left',40);
        line.Set('chart.gutter.right',10);
        line.Set('chart.gutter.bottom',50);
        line.Set('chart.filled', true);
        line.Set('chart.filled.accumulative',true);
        line.Set('chart.key', ['ABC', 'DEF']);
        line.Set('chart.tickmarks.dot.color','white');
        line.Set('chart.backgroundGridAutofitNumvlines',data.length);
        line.Set('key.position','gutter'); // or graph
        line.Set('chart.ymin',0);
        line.Set('chart.ymax',250);
        line.Set('chart.numyticks',5);
        line.Set('chart.key.position.x',50);
        line.Set('chart.key.position.y',10);
        line.draw();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, how do you tell RGraph to just draw the points with data and ignore those without whilst keeping all the date points?

Thanks
Abe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that RGraph doesn't do it, so I've resorted to ChartJS and on the whole it works - see https://jsfiddle.net/Abeeee/6xrk1m23/41/

```
<script type='text/JavaScript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.3/Chart.js'></script>

<div style="width:100%; height:300px">
  <canvas id="canvas" style='width:100%; height:300px'></canvas>
</div>

<button id='on'>
  Span Gaps=true
</button>

<button id='off'>
  Span Gaps=false
</button> 


var config = {
       type: 'line',
       data: {
       labels: ['Jan\n2018', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
       datasets: [{
          label: 'Red',
          borderColor: '#FF0000',
          backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
             data: [
    10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, undefined, 80, 90, 100, 90, 80
             ],
           }, {
             label: 'Blue',
             borderColor: '#0000FF',
             backgroundColor: '#0000FF',
             data: [
               10, 20, undefined, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 92, undefined, 90, 80
             ],
           }]
        },
        options: {
           spanGaps: true,
           responsive: true,
           maintainAspectRatio: false,
           title: {
           display: true,
           text: 'Chart.js Line Chart - Stacked Area'
           },
           tooltips: {
           mode: 'index',
       },
       hover: {
         mode: 'index'
       },
       scales: {
          xAxes: [{
          scaleLabel: {
             display: true,
             labelString: 'Month'
          }
       }],
       yAxes: [{
           stacked: true,
           scaleLabel: {
              display: true,
              labelString: 'Value'
           }
       }]
     }
  }
};

var ctx1 = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx1, config);

$("#on").on("click", function() {
  myChart.options.spanGaps=true;
  myChart.update();
});

$("#off").on("click", function() {
  myChart.options.spanGaps=false;
  myChart.update();
});
```

Use the buttons to switch spanGaps on and off.

Note, I say on the whole, as it fixes my problem (of underlying data gaps), but it seems to fail to span if the dataset is sitting on top of another (a ChartJS bug perhaps?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use null values in your data. The behaviour is slightly different for a single dataset vs multiple data sets though:

```
var data = [4,8,6,3,5,4,2,null,8,6,3,5,8,null,4,9,8];
```

Comment: The demo IS showing nulls and they are not spanning those gaps.